# Testing an association model helper method rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have two models, `User` and `Account`.

```
# account.rb
belongs_to :user

# user.rb
has_one :account
```

`Account` has an attribute `name`. And in my views, I was calling `current_user.account.name` multiple times, and I heard that's not the great of a way to do it. So I was incredibly swift, and I created the following method in my `user.rb`

```
def account_name
  self.account.name
end
```

So now in my view, I can simply call `current_user.account_name`, and if the association changes, I only update it in one place. BUT my question is, do I test this method? If I do, how do I test it without any mystery guests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree there is nothing wrong with current_user.account.name - while Sandi Metz would tell us "User knows too much about Account" this is kind of the thing you can't really avoid w/ Active Record.

If you found you were doing a lot of these methods *all over* the User model you could use the rails delegate method:

```
  delegate :name, :to => :account, :prefix => true
```

using the :prefix => true option will prefix the method in the User model so it is account_name.  In this case I would assume you could write a very simple unit test on the method that it returns **something** just incase the attribute in account would ever change your test would fail so you would know you need to update the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for the `delegate` option. That's new to me. And, fair enough, maybe nothing is wrong with using `current_user.account.name`, however, would you then write a test to test that `account.name` does not change? Similar to how you suggested writing a test for your suggested code?

Comment: If you use `delegate` you should only need to test that the target object (Account in this case) responds to :name.  The Rails library tests would handle testing their flavor of the `delegate` method - so to your point, using delegate would remove some of the method chaining and you'd be solely testing that a delegator is created in user that sends `account_name` to something and gets something back (not a `NoMethodError` )

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

1. There's nothing wrong with current_user.account.name
2. There's no difference between calling it as current_user.account.name, or making current_user.account_name call it for you
3. You're probably not calling current_user in the model, like you say
4. You should have a spec for it if you use it

Personally I see no good reason for any of this. Just use current_user.account.name.

If you are worrying about efficiency, have current_user return a user that joins account.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit off-topic. So, apologies in advance if it's not interesting or helpful.

TL;DR: Don't put knowledge of your models in your views. Keep your controllers skinny. Here's how I've been doing it.

In my current project, I've been working to make sure my views have absolutely no knowledge of anything about the rest of the system (to reduce coupling). This way, if you decide to change how you implement something (say, `current_user.account.name` versus `current_user.account_name`), then you don't have to go into your views and make changes.

Every controller action provides a `@results` hash that contains everything the view needs to render correctly. The structure of the `@results` hash is essentially a contract between the view and the controller.

So, in my controller, `@results` might look something like `{current_user: {account: {name: 'foo'}}}`. And in my view, I'd do something like `@results[:current_user][:account][:name]`. I like using a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` so I could also do `@results['current_user']['account']['name']` and not have things blow up or misbehave.

Also, I've been moving as much logic as I can out of controllers into service objects (I call them 'managers'). I find my managers (which are POROs) a lot easier to test than controllers. So, I might have:

```
# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController
  def create
    @results = SomeManager.create(params)
    if @results[:success]
      # happy routing
    else
      # sad routing
    end
  end
end
```

Now, my controllers are super skinny and contain no logic other than routing. They don't know anything about my models. (In fact, almost all of my controller actions look exactly the same with essentially the same six lines of code.) Again, I like this because it creates separation.

Naturally, I need the manager:

```
#app/managers/some_manager.rb
class SomeManager
  class << self
    def create(params)
      # do stuff that ends up creating the @results hash
      # if things went well, the return will include success: true
      # if things did not go well, the return will not include a :success key
    end
  end
end
```

So, in truth, the structure of `@results` is a contract between the view and the manager, not between the view and the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it very much. But do you not run into the same problem as I described above, if 'name' attribute changes to 'title', would you not need to change your view calls from @results['current_user']['account']['name'] to  @results['current_user']['account']['title']?

Comment: You don't necessarily run into the same problem. Your hash could still be @results['current_user']['account']['name'] even if the 'name' value was actually coming from current_user.account.title. You could change the hash construction logic in your manager to use 'title' for the 'name' value and your view would be none-the-wiser.

Comment: Cool, I see how this makes life easier. How would you update the hash with that change? Sorry if that's a complex thing to answer

Comment: Let's assume (a) controller is UserController, (b) action is show, and (c) params includes :id. In UserManager.show, you might do something like: user = User.find(params[:id]); @results = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new; @results[:current_user] = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(user.as_json); @results[:current_user][:account] = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(user.account.as_json); @results[:current_user][:account][:name] = user.account.title